# Making Facebook Dialog Feed Box appear in the same window as a modal instead of popup of a page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like Facebook Dialog Feed to appear as a modal in the same page.  The user is authenticated earlier before this call, using PHP.  I tried using the `iframe` property for display, but it is still appearing as a popup.

The code is below:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
   FB.init({ appId: '****************', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
   if (typeof facebookInit == 'function') {
       facebookInit();
   }
};

(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));

function facebookInit() {
  FB.ui({
    url : 'http://url.com',
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Hey',
    link: 'http://url.com',
    display: 'iframe',
    picture: '',
    caption: fb_description,
    }, function (response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            window.location = "/hello";
        } else {
            window.location = "/hello";
        }
    }
  ); 
}
```

Is there a reason why this is appearing as a popup and not appearing as a modal?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to show the feed dialog in the same window instead of popup is to use the direct url redirection.

You can use it like this-

```
function facebookInit() {
    var app_id = "{app-id}";
    var fb_description = "{description}";
    var redirect_uri = "{redirect-url}";
    var link = "{link to share}";
    var name = "{name}";

    var url =   "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?"+
                "app_id="+app_id+
                "&caption="+fb_description+
                "&link="+link+
                "&name="+name+
                "&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri;

    location.href = url;
}
```

**Edit:**

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) says-

> If you are using the JavaScript SDK, this will default to a modal iframe type for people logged into your app or async when using **within a game on Facebook.com**, and a popup window for everyone else

If your app is inside the facebook, then only it will open as a model iframe type, else, a popup or completely on window will be shown.

Comment: You dont need that, redirecting the above url will open the dialog automatically, did you tried?

Comment: but that will redirect the entire page, right?  I want to have it appear as a modal.  Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly you mean by `appear as modal`?

Comment: I mean, look like a popup, but appear within the page.  I like the popup, I just don't want it to be read by browsers as a popup, and I don't want it to have a separate URL.  Does this make sense?

Comment: See there are only and only 2 options: 1 simple popup , second what I've shared.

Comment: There's no option using display iframe that can make it a modal type object?  Sorry to harp on this, but I've seen it elsewhere, unless this has changed

Comment: No I dont think so, but if you can show where you have seen this may be I could help you with that

Comment: I was trying to follow along with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880113/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-ui-opens-a-popup-window.  Also, in the developer docs for FB for the FB.ui feed (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog), I see the description: "If you are using the JavaScript SDK, this will default to a modal iframe type for people logged into your app"

Comment: But then your app should be inside the facebook, check the edit.

Comment: So there's no way to do this if it's an external web page?

Comment: PS if the discussion helped, you may accept/vote the ans so that the discussion may close. Good luck :)